# Can I work around UnitTest's SystemExit handler?

Tags: python, unix, exit, python-unittest, low-level

I'm rewriting a afl-fuzz (a C application) to Python. Since I don't have enough understanding of its inner workings, I would like to replicate its functionality as close as possible.

I'm trying to run a functional test of a routine that forks Python interpreter, runs `execve` and if it fails, reports failure to its caller by returning 42. The test runs nice outside of unittest, but fails when put into it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import unittest


def run_test():
    x = os.fork()
    if not x:
        sys.exit(42)
    waitpid_result, status = os.waitpid(x, os.WUNTRACED)
    print(os.WEXITSTATUS(status))


class ForkFunctionalTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_exercise_fork(self):
        run_test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Expecting "42" as output:')
    run_test()
    print('\nAnd here goes unexpected SystemExit error:')
    unittest.main()
```

Here's how it fails:

```
Expecting "42" as output:
42

And here goes unexpected SystemExit error:
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_exercise_fork (__main__.ForkFunctionalTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "afl-fuzz2.py", line 23, in test_exercise_fork
    run_test()
  File "afl-fuzz2.py", line 15, in run_test
    sys.exit(42)
SystemExit: 42

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
1
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.014s

OK
```

Is there a way to make unittest work with this function without changing run_test? I tried os._exit instead of sys.exit(), but it made the program die in both processes.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that os._exit actually worked, but in my unit tests I needed to mock it out given that I mocked out os.fork. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.exit()` raises a SystemExit class exception, which, if not caught, quits the program. You can try to catch the exception:

```
def text_exercise_fork(self):
    try:
        run_test()
    except SystemExit as e:
        print(e.args[0])
```

Comment: Thanks. The thing is that I don't want to catch it, I want to actually have the forked process die with exit code = 42.